# If $ A ∈ M_n$ be positive definite then $(x^∗ Ax)(y^∗A^{−1} y) ≥ |x^∗ y|^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $ A ∈ M_n$ be positive definite, and let $x, y ∈ \mathbb{C}^n$.

Why does $(x^∗ Ax)(y^∗A^{−1} y) ≥
|x^∗ y|^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fill in the right "one" and use Cauchy-Schwarz, we have
\begin{align*}
  \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}
  \abs{x^*y}^2 &= \abs{x^*A^{1/2}A^{-1/2}y}^2\\
               &= \abs{(A^{1/2}x)^*A^{-1/2}y}^2\\
               &\le (A^{1/2}x)^*(A^{1/2}x) \cdot (A^{-1/2}y)^*A^{-1/2}y\\
               &= (x^*Ax)(y^*A^{-1}y)
\end{align*}